# Is there a pythonic way to get two elements from the list (first, second)...(last, first)

Tags: python, list

```
def convert_number_into_months_range(number):
    zodiac_months = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2]
    first_month = zodiac_months[number]
    if number == len(zodiac_months) - 1:
        second_month = zodiac_months[0]
    else:
        second_month = zodiac_months[number + 1]
    return first_month, second_month
```

This is my example. It works, but looks unpythonic.
On Input we have an index of the list. On return we have tuple of (index, index+1) elements of the list.
If the index is pointing on the last element then we should get (last, first) elements.
Is there are way to do it in more pythonicaly?

Comment: Use `(number + 1) % len(zodiac_months)` to produce `0` when `number` is the last index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def convert_number_into_months_range(number):
    zodiac_months = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2]
    return zodiac_months[number], zodiac_months[(number + 1) % len(zodiac_months)])
```

Comment: down vote? But why?

Comment: The return should be `return zodiac_months[number], zodiac_months[(number + 1) % len(zodiac_months)]` so that the indexing does not depend on the values of the list. (I am not the downvoter.)

Comment: Oh! how have I missed that! updated, thanks :)

Comment: Thank you guys! I've one more way that is very specific to Python:

Comment: `second_month = zodiac_months[number + 1 - len(zodiac_months)]` Here we use negative indexing, calculating the second number from the right side of the list.